# Angular 4 ng-model form binding

Tags: angular

I have a form to edit a customer.
The form is dynamic as the users can create and order fields.

I have a first call that gives me the form's template and I need to bind the customer's value to it.

This is my code :

```
<form (ngSubmit)="saveCustomer($event); $event.preventDefault()">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 pb10">
        <h2>{{customerMapped?.name}}</h2>
        <span>{{customerMapped?.street}}</span><br/>
        <span>{{customerMapped?.zip}} {{customerMapped?.city}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12" *ngFor="let section of template?.sections">
        <h3 class="bordered-top pt10">{{section.displayName}}</h3>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6" *ngFor="let attribute of section?.attributes">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="code">{{attribute.displayName}}</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{attribute.name}}"
                    name="customerMapped[attribute.name]"
                    [ngModel]="customerMapped[attribute.name]"
                    (ngModelChange)="customerMapped[attribute.name] = $event"
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I do a console.log(this.customerMapped) in the saveCustomer method, it shows me the good datas and when I change the input value, it changes the customerMapped value.

Does that ring a bell for anyone ? :-)

**EDIT**

The inputs are now filled but they're filled with wrong values, it's like the binding doesn't care about my [attribute.name] dynamic name :

[image]
[image]

**LAST EDIT**

To make it work, I had to do :

```
<label for="code">{{attribute.displayName}}</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{attribute.name}}" name="{{attribute.name}}" 
[ngModel]="customerMapped[attribute.name]"
(ngModelChange)="customerMapped[attribute.name] = $event"/>
```

and re-organize my object in order to have all the values from attribute at the root level.

[image]

Comment: what exactly do you want didn't get your problem

Comment: my customerMapped object isn't empty but the input aren't filled with the values.

Comment: i think you got one from below post where u did wrong

Comment: You need to give unique Id to id="{{attribute.name}}" its happen just because you update Id at run time for field that is not correct

Comment: they have a unique id, attribute.name is a unique value.

Comment: @banibanc you are changing this value at [ngModel]="customerMapped[attribute.name]" so how does it unique?

Comment: Could you please show the content of your variables in JSON format?

Answer (score 0):

`ngModel` should be in square brackets

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{attribute.name}}"
        name="customerMapped[attribute.name]"
        [ngModel]="customerMapped[attribute.name]"
        (ngModelChange)="customerMapped[attribute.name] = $event"/>
```

Comment: The input is now filled but not with the right data, they're all filled with the same data.

Comment: use `[(ngModel)]` and `(ngModelChange)`. separately.